# Is it correct to say "My T-shirt is so tight that my chest sticks out"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

I am wearing a very tight T-shirt that people can see the shape of my chest.

> [stick out](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/stick-out) phrasal verb
>
> 1- if something sticks out, you notice it because part of it comes out
> further than the rest of a surface
>
> "The children were so thin their ribs stuck out."

The ribs did not actually poke out of the bodies, and we can only see the shape of the ribs.

Could I try to say the similar thing?

“**My T-shirt is so tight that my chest sticks out.**”

Answer (score 2):

Can you say, "My T-shirt is so tight that my chest sticks out"? Certainly. As you apparently understand, "sticks out" does not necessarily mean "pokes through the covering".

This sentence would make more sense coming from a woman, but a man might say it if he has a prominent chest.